# PHP Recursion doesn't seem to be traversing all avenues

Tags: php, recursion, maze

This program is supposed to find all the possible ways down through a maze, and save the farthest distance down it got in a global variable. Instead it only travels one path and then ends? I'm guessing I'm not using recursion correctly or something. $draw_co2 is an array of 0 and 1s, where 1 is a path and 0 is a wall. I've included the output from the points collected by $GLOBALS['route'] on top of the maze itself below. Based on the code, I'd expect the whole main red branch to be white?

I was using else if instead of just else. As mentioned below, use else in order to explore all branches.

Comment: Your code seems correct, what I believe is happening is that it's going as far as it can, gets to a dead end and never 'turns' around. Your code doesn't look like it will backtrack and try a different route from what I understand of it. Because of the way your code is weighted in if/else statements it's likely it's always ending in that position due to having a certain order priority.

Comment: I'd expect the code to explore both/all branches though because of the if statements. Like if both left and right are 1, i'd expect there to be 2 branches that get explored. This traverses only a single path? at the very least I'd expect it to move right and left a little as part of an alternate path. It's obviously not creating branches with the ifs, and I don't understand why.

Comment: This happens because of your `else`s. Remove the `else` from the `if` to explore all option - currently it only take the first available option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with recursion in the code snippet. My best guess is that the only thing that could be causing this, is `$draw_co2`. I think there is no path in `$draw_co2` which recursion can traverse. For testing, I would recommend to create a definite path in the array `$draw_co2` and pass the starting coordinates in the recursion function. Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

If you change all of your `else if`s to only `if`, this could traverse all paths.

Comment: I've updated the post to include a picture of the output. I don't see how $draw_co2 could be the issue.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. This is what you get when you code without sleep. Good catch my man.